# C# create and manipulate an array of Employee objects

Tags: c#, arrays

Create:

This class defines an Employee.
Member variables: ID (int), name (string), salary (double)
Member Methods: Constructors, input/output methods that perform I/O for an employee

Create:

This class defines an array of Employees
Member variables: An array of Employee, SIZE (int), currentSize (int)
Member Methods: Constructors, input/output methods, search/insert/delete/update methods.

Not sure exactly how to store 3 Employee variables inside a single array index.

Updated:

```
   using System;
   using System.Collections.Generic;
   using System.Linq;
   using System.Text;
   using System.Threading.Tasks;

   namespace ConsoleApplication16
   {

    class Employee
    {
        protected int id;
        protected string name;
        protected double salary;


        public Employee()
        {
        }

        public Employee(int _id, string nm, double sal)
        {
            id = _id;
            name = nm;
            salary = sal;
        }


        public void PrintEmployee()
        {

            Console.WriteLine("id: {0}", id);
            Console.WriteLine("Name: {0}", name);
            Console.WriteLine("Salary: {0}", salary);


        }


    }


    class EmployeeArray : Employee
    {
        private Employee[] a;
        private int currSize;
        private const int SIZE = 100;

        public EmployeeArray()
            : base()
        {

        }
        public EmployeeArray(int s, int _id, string nm, double sal)
            : base(_id, nm, sal)
        {
            a = new Employee[SIZE];
            if (s > SIZE)
                Console.WriteLine("Array size is overflow!");
            else if (s == SIZE)
                Console.WriteLine("Array is full.");
            else
                currSize = s;




        }

        public void Input()
        {    
            a = new Employee[3];
            for (int i = 0; i < currSize; i++)
            {
                a[i] = new Employee(id, name, salary);
            }



        }
        public void Output()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Array is: ");
            foreach (Employee x in a)
                Console.WriteLine("a[{0}]= {1}", name, x);


        }




        public int Search(int key)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < currSize; i++)
            {
                //if (a[i] == key)
                //    return i;
            }
            return -1;
        }

        public void Insert()
        {
            if (currSize == SIZE)
            {
                Console.Write("Array is full! ");
                return;
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Enter a number to insert: ");
            int y = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("Enter the index to where it is to insert: ");
            int pos = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            for (int i = currSize; i > pos; i--)
                a[i] = a[i - 1];


            //a[pos] = y;
            currSize++;
        }

        public void Delete()
        {
            if (currSize == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Array is empty! ");
                return;
            }
            Console.Write("Delete by value (1) or by index (2):  ");
            int key = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            int pos = -1;
            if (key == 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Enter the number to delete: ");
                int d = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                pos = Search(d);
                while (pos == -1)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("The number does not exist, enter again: ");
                    d = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    pos = Search(d);
                }
            }
            else if (key == 2)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Enter the index to delete from: ");
                pos = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                while (pos < 0 || pos > currSize)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("The index is out of range, enter again: ");
                    pos = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                }

            }
            else
                return;

            for (int i = pos; i < currSize; i++)
                a[i] = a[i + 1];

            currSize--;
            if (currSize <= 0)
                Console.Write("Array is empty! ");
        }

        public void Update()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the index where to update: ");
            int pos = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            while (pos < 0 || pos >= currSize)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The index you entered is not valid, enter again: ");
                pos = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the new value: ");
            int x = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            //a[pos] = x;
            Console.Write("Update complete! ");
        }


    }
    class Program
    {
        //static char ShowMenu()
        //{
        //    Console.WriteLine("\nEnter the letter of operation: \n(o)Print, (s)Search, (i)Insertion, (d)Deletion, (u)Update, (e)Exit\n");
        //    return char.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        //}
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //char sel = ' ';
            Console.Write("Enter number of Employees; ");
            int i = 0;
            int s = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            while ( i < s )
            {


                Console.WriteLine("");
                Console.WriteLine("");

                Console.WriteLine("Enter id: ");
                int _id = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());


                Console.WriteLine("");
                Console.WriteLine("Enter Name: ");
                string nm = Console.ReadLine();

                Console.WriteLine("");
                Console.WriteLine("Enter Salary: ");
                double sal = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                EmployeeArray arr = new EmployeeArray(s, _id, nm, sal);


                i++;
            }



        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you trying to store three things at a single index? That's not how arrays work.

Answer (score 3):

This reads like homework but I'll help you out.

You create your employee class with it's three members and methods.

then you create an array of employee objects.

```
//How Many employee objects do you need. Let's assume 10 for example
int NUM = 10; 

Employee[] employees = new Employee[NUM]; // Declare an An array of employee's of length 10  (zero indexed from 0 - 9)

//Assuming you have made Getters and Setters

//Then if you need to access an employee object's member(s)
employees[0].getId(); //get the first employee's id
employees[0].getName(); //get the first employee's name
employees[0].getSalary(); //get the first employee's name

// Or set them like
employees[4].setId(12); //set the fifth employee's id to 12
employees[4].setName("Joe Bloggs"); //set the fifth employee's name to Joe Bloggs
employees[4].setSalary("30000"); //set the fifth employee's salary to 30000
```

[MSDN C# Arrays](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288453%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

[MSDN Classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9afc042.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of problems with the code you posted. I'm just going to highlight a few issues, especially since this implementing arrays sounds a lot like computer science homework.

1. `EmployeeArray` inherits from `Employee`. Think about the meaning of `public` and `private` keywords and base classes.
2. Your functions all do more than one thing. This really complicates your code, and is going to result in bugs. Focus on straightforward code that does one thing and communicates what it does.
3. Users could crash your program in several places by entering something other than a number.

Lastly, to directly answer your question, you can access arrays through an index. You can't store three separate `Employee` objects in the same index. You've accessed array objects in other parts of your code, so it seems like you understand that you can store different values in different indexes.

Comment: i updated my code a little. Now I can not get array to print in the  Output() method. What do I need to need in the main to print array?